# Three JS - Text on canvas flickering

Tags: canvas, text, three.js, 2d, flicker

I'm drawing 2d text using the canvas approach, however I get heavy flickering when I rotate or move the camera with controls. I'm using `Verdana 16px` font. Making the font size bigger makes the text look better upfront, but doesn't make the flickering go away.

**What is causing this flickering? (btw I tried removing transparency on the text, that didn't help...)**

```
    // create a canvas element
    var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    context1.font = "40px Verdana";
    context1.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    context1.fillText(text, 0, 30);

    // canvas contents will be used for a texture
    var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1);
    texture1.needsUpdate = true;

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture1, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    material1.transparent = true;

    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas1.width, canvas1.height),
        material1
        );
```

[image]

Comment: It happens way worse when the camera is in front and under the text (looking up), and is almost not there when the camera is above the text (looking down)...

Comment: what is your cameras near and far plane?

Comment: @gaitat: near is 1, and far is 10000

Comment: Just tried several combinations, `1-1000`, `1-100`, `10-100`, `10-1000`, `10-10000`. All give the same effect. No problem when I don't change the camera and just approach the "2D" text. But as soon as I rotate the camera it starts flickering...

Comment: can you create a fiddle? what if you dont use rgba fill and just rgb?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that several canvases overlap each other.

By default, the canvases are very large, you can see this by setting the color or by setting - `material1.transparent = false;`

To avoid flickering, you need to set the size so that they do not overlap.

```
canvas1.width = 40;
canvas1.height = 20;
```